# Show alert if less buttons are selected than it should be

Tags: jquery, alert

I have a grid of buttons, lets say user opens up the grid and selects button "4", it will display buttons "A" to "D" below (.answerBtns). Now if user enters in the number "3" in the "Number of Answers" text-box (#numberAnswerTxt), then if the user tries to select more than 3 buttons, it will come up with an alert stating you cannot go beyond limit, deselect a button. You can try this yourself.

But what I want to do is that lets say the user selects less buttons and lets say selects only 1 button when the user is suppose to select 3 buttons (user typed in number 3 in "Number of Answers" text-box), what I want is that if the user clicks on the "Add Question" button, it should display an alert saying "least buttons are selected, please select more buttons". The alert should appear in the "insertQuestion(this.form)".

How can this be done?

There are two functions to look at to help you and these are the last two functions in the javascript code which are:

```
function btnclick(btn)
```

and

```
function insertQuestion(form)
```

Code is in Jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8fXXR/1/)

Comment: Indenting your code would make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mentioned the functions you should look at in my edit to make it easier

Comment: Click the TidyUp button in jsFiddle, save the edit, and update your answer. Makes it easier for all of us :)

Comment: sorry, the code has been tidy up, saved and included in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think if you put this on insertQuestion(form) it will solve your problem

```
if ($('.answerBtnsOn').length != $('#numberAnswerTxt').val()) {
     alertErrors ="\nplease add more answer";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/thejase/8fXXR/6/

Just a thought: disable the button until they can use it.

Comment: Hi, I have other elements other than selecting answers, I have creating question, answer weight and answer duration so too many factors to consider so I won't use button example for this situation but this is very useful for other projects if I need to use it so thank you very much